# Why does counted? return true in one case and false in the other?

Tags: clojure

```
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (def x (repeat 10 1))
#'user/x
user=> (counted? x)
false
user=> (def x (list 1 2 3))
#'user/x
user=> (counted? x)
true
user=>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `(repeat 10 1)` returns a `LazySeq`
- `(list 1 2 3)` returns a `PersistentList`

Obviously there is no way of knowing how many items are in a lazy sequence until that sequence is evaluated.

`counted?` returns true for any class which implements the `clojure.lang.Counted` interface.

Comment: Ok ... just to complete the picture. Even after a doall counted? returns false. doall returns the same list, a LazySeq. You can always check the type using (class xs).  To convert a LazySeq to a PersistentList you can use (into () myLazySeq)